# Use Datasource Properties in XPath Expression of SoapUI

Tags: xpath, properties, soapui

I need to know whether it is possible to use a datasource property in XPath Expression panel of XPath Match Configuration. For instance, if we have the following XML document:

```
<ns1:Ions>
  <ns1:Ion>UI</ns1:Ion>
  <ns1:IonType>X</ns1:IonType>
  <ns1:StartDate>2010-05-10</ns1:StartDate>
</ns1:Ions>
<ns1:Ions>
  <ns1:Ion>HH</ns1:Ion>
  <ns1:IonType>RI</ns1:IonType>
  <ns1:StartDate>1998-11-23</ns1:StartDate>
</ns1:Ions>
<ns1:Ions>
  <ns1:Ion>CF</ns1:Ion>
  <ns1:IonType>A</ns1:IonType>
  <ns1:StartDate>2000-06-10</ns1:StartDate>
</ns1:Ions>
```

I need to evaluate to see whether a content of `IonType` is '*A*' only if its sibling node, `Ion`, has a value of '*CF*'. I was hoping to accomplish this by setting XPath Match Configuration as following:

**XPath Expression** (DataSourceInput#ION is 'CF')

```
declare namespace ns1='http://my.namespace.com';
//ns1:Ions[ns1:Ion[text()=${DataSourceInput#ION}]]/ns1:IonType/text()
```

**Expected Results** (DataSourceInput#ION_TYPE is 'A')

```
${DataSourceInput#ION_TYPE}
```

Running the test would result in SoapUI [Pro] to error the following, **Missing content for xpath declare**. If I replace `${DataSourceInput#ION}` with an actual value, i.e. 'CF', the test works accordingly (I even tried place single quotes around `${DataSourceInput#ION}`, but it didn't work).

Is there another way of accomplish this in SoapUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try what you do and it works for me if I put single quotes around the property:

```
declare namespace ns1='http://my.namespace.com';
//ns1:Ions[ns1:Ion[text()='${DataSourceInput#ION}']]/ns1:IonType/text()
```

Did you check that testStep name is exactly DataSourceInput? If there are spaces in the TestStep name (i.e your testStep name is Data Source Input you have to put `${Data Source Input#ION}`).

Anyway I give you another way to do so, you can add a testStep of type groovy script after the testStep where you are getting the `<Ions>`response, and check the assert here like follows:

```
// get xml holder
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def ionsHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("IonsTestStepName#response");

// generate xpath expression
def xpathExpression = "//*:Ions[*:Ion[text()='" + context.expand('${DataSourceInput#ION}') + "']]/*:IonType/text()";
log.info xpathExpression;

// get the node value
def nodeValue = ionsHolder.getNodeValue(xpathExpression);

// check expected value
assert nodeValue == context.expand('${DataSourceInput#ION_TYPE}'),'ERROR IONS VALUE';
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you. I do not know why placing the property inside a single quotation did not work initially, but after implementing a closely similar Groovy script solution, I recreated an assertion match and was able to pull the data out accordingly. Nonetheless, due to the possibility of property's content not being provided and not wanting for the assertion to fail because of a non-existing value of the property, I had to implement the logic in the script to handle such scenario.